# Will a sniper with squad sight on overwatch fire at targets allies can see?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If I have a sniper on overwatch, and that sniper has the Squad Sight skill, will the sniper take reaction shots at enemies seen by fellow soldiers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes - if the sniper has LOS as well (as in nothing is blocking his shot to the alien, such as a rock or car.)

Comment: This is true even if he is in Pistol Overwatch (even though he couldn't use SS to get a normal shot).