# Can a Squad Sight Sniper use Mindfray on an enemy outside their line of sight?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Can a psionic sniper with the Squad Sight ability use Mindfray on an enemy not in their line of sight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** The only abilities that work with Squadsight are those that use the sniper rifle, namely standard fire, Headshot, and Disabling Shot.

Comment: hmmm. according to this [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93917/will-a-sniper-with-squad-sight-on-overwatch-fire-at-targets-allies-can-see) you can activate a overwatch w/ a squad sight sniper. maybe ill try if i can mindfray with a sniper later when i get back home.

Comment: Overwatch does work with Squad Sight. But you're right that psionic powers don't.

Comment: Overwatch works fine with Squadsight.

Comment: Yep, overwatch and squadsight is a nice combo esp when you have training roulette enabled to add in fun skills like covering fire and sentinel

Comment: Also note that although the pistol does not benefit from Squadsight on your turn, it does on Overwatch.  Likely a bug/exploit, but it allows you to move your sniper and still get some use (particularly if he/she has Gunslinger).